# How to get preview of Google Drawing files in our site by connecting to Google API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I had some files in my Google Drawings, and now I want to display the preview of those images in my site. I'm using PHP language. I've created my Google API, seeing this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php). But I can't find the best solution to fix my problem. Can someone help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the files and use `thumbnailLink` attribute as a link for the preview image.

```
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$files = $service->files->list();

foreach ($files["items"] as &$file) {
  echo $file->thumbnailLink;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me clearly.. I don't even know the correct process how to connect to google API..